# Suffix -dom and -ness

Tags: difference, grammaticality, suffixes

Is there any difference between those suffixes (-dom and -ness) when both of them can be applied to a word?

Example:

- [richness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/richness)

> 1. (uncountable) The state or quality of being rich; wealthiness, wealth, riches.

- [richdom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/richdom)

> 1. (rare) Wealth; riches; richness; prosperity  (Wiktionary)

Comment: in your example, yes: "richness" is a valid word that is commonly used, while "richdom" is not a word I've ever heard.

Answer (score 3):

***richdom*** is a rare obsolete word inherited from German. Don't use it. But when it *was* in use, the primary meaning was "Royal power, sovereignty" ("kingdom" was an even rarer sense of an already rare word). The only current English words I can identify that differ only by suffix ***-ness*** or ***-dom*** are ***heathenness*** and ***heathendom***.

According to the full OED, both can be used as nouns, but only ***heathenness*** can be used as an adjective (which I confess I don't understand).

---

Both suffixes are still "productive", but note that ***-ness*** normally only forms abstract "nouns of state" (***kindness, laziness*** = the states of being kind or lazy), whereas ***-dom*** (which also generates such terms) can additionally be used to form words with a (figurative) sense of ‘domain, realm’.

Hence the nonce-word ***Cockneydom*** would mean "the land where the Cockneys live", as opposed to ***Cockneyness***, which would mean "the state / quality of being a Cockney".

Comment: There's also [chiefdom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chiefdom) and [chiefness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chiefness), which might be more useful for learners to know  but both are nouns.

Comment: I did notice ***chiefness*** when trawling through [onelook](https://www.onelook.com/) matches for "?????ness", but I just assumed it was a garbage entry. I see now from the full OED that it *did* exist with the sense ***The chief quality; supremacy, superiority*** - but it's now obsolete, with the most recent citation being 1661, so it's not obvious to me that it's useful to learners. It doesn't mean the same as ***chiefdom*** (The estate, position or dominion of a chief; headship, leadership, chief place), though.